# where is ViewPager in the android compatibility package?

Tags: android

I've got the android compatibility package and want to experiment with the `ViewPager`. http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

However, i can't find this class. where is it? after I generated the javadocs (per the link above, the class file is not in the javadocs either).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`? Check the source of the compatibility package, unless you are using an old version, it should be there.

Comment: all i see in that namespace is MenuCompat.java. on my file system: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\compatibility\v4\src\java\android\support\v4\view there is only that file.

Comment: it turns out i only have Android Compatibility package, revision 2. further complicating my understanding is that there's a revision 3, but then a version with the revision (i.e. revision 2, v4 or revision 3, v4). strange. also, as a last gotcha, i forgot to run the sdk manager as administrator on windows 7. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

double check if your android compatability source contains the file...

had the same problem and tried to fix it (ViewPager not found - cannot be resolved) .. and finally found out that my included lib (source) simply didnt contain it...

good luck!